# RgbdslamV2 getting coordinates of localization

Tags: ros, slam, localization, navigation, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I know this question have been asked before, but i couldnt find out how does it works here on Version2 of RGBDslam.
How can i get the coordinates of localization?
And how to use /tf properly?

thanks
best

Michael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172967/rgbdslamv2-getting-coordinates-of-localization/) by [Miško](https://answers.ros.org/users/9746/mi%C5%A1ko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-06-09**:
Looking forward for that too as I need to send them to a FMU of a quadrotor for autonomous nav!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the answer.
It is simple, build in feature.
On menu, go to I/O -> Save Trajectory Estimate
Than you got a time samp, with coordinates of position x, y, z, and rotation x,y,z, and w.

---

Originally posted by [Miško](https://answers.ros.org/users/9746/mi%C5%A1ko/) with karma: 31 on 2014-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0